# date-fns: add days in an arbitrary timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst, date-fns

I need a function `f` to add 7 days to a given Date in a given timezone (which is not the system time zone). The function should take DST changes in account.
Is it possible to implement `f` using `date-fns` or one of its timezone plugins?

Here are some examples of desired behavior:

```
const a = new Date(2019, 3, 8, 0, 0)
const b = f(a, 'Europe/Brussels')
console.log(dateFns.differenceInHours(b, a)) // Should be 168
```

```
const a = new Date(2019, 3, 8, 0, 0)
const b = f(a, 'America/Los_Angeles')
console.log(dateFns.differenceInHours(b, a)) // Should be 167 due to spring-forward on 10th March
```